# Top Identity Header is not in page width in IE - CSS Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

On [this page](http://pwtest.iurecsports.org/) I can not get IE to show the crimson identity header in full width of the page. However it works fine in FF and Chrome. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This is definitely an unusual IE9 bug. First of all, the problem doesn't exist in compatibility view (IE7). I'm trying all kinds of things in IE developer toolbar. It shows the body tag itself as not stretching all the way across, but this problem stops if you entirely delete the #identity div and its sibling table, but not if you only delete one or the other, nor if you completely turn off declared styles on those, nor if you empty their contents entirely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Try giving `#header` `width: 100%;` instead of `width: auto;`</strike>

Add:

```
body, html { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

to your CSS file.

Comment: Tried it now, did not work :(

Comment: Could you post a screen shot. I'm on a Mac but might be able to suss it out if i can see what you're seeing.

Comment: OK. Try "body, html { padding: 0; margin: 0; }" in your css file.

Comment: Also you have topmargin="5" on your body tag which is probably creating the white space above in IE

Comment: chef, padding and margin solved it. do you think it could possibly solve other IE issues such as mislocation of buttons on the right which needs to be vertical but is horizontal??

Comment: The buttons on the right are contained in a table. Try setting the width of the table to 188px instead of 33%. Might work. Might not

Comment: that actually did not solve, I **put them in a different rows** and that solved it. But thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a conditional statement for IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
/*Put your styles specific for ie below*/

</style>
<![endif]-->
```